# Chrome memory leak on dispatchEvent

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-management, memory-leaks, puppeteer

```
        const focusEvent = new FocusEvent('focus', {
            bubbles: true   
        });

        // Trigger the input value in the search box
        const inputEvent = new InputEvent('input', {
            bubbles: true
        });

        // Send enter
        const keyEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
            code: 'Enter',
            key: 'Enter',
            keyCode: 13,
            view: window,
            bubbles: true
        });

        let search = document.querySelector('#side > div._1Ra05 > div > label > div > div._1awRl.copyable-text.selectable-text');

        function searchList(name = "") {
            try {
                search.textContent = name;
                search.dispatchEvent(focusEvent);
                search.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);
                search.dispatchEvent(keyEvent);

                search.removeEventListener('focus', focusEvent);
                search.removeEventListener('input', inputEvent);
                search.removeEventListener('keydown', keyEvent);

            } catch { console.log(error); };
        }
```

I'm using `puppeteer` and inside `await page.evaluate(async ({` i have a loop that calls the `function searchList` on each `100 ms`, the problem is the browser mem usage is growing constantly, after 30min its over 1GB of ram.

I discovered that whos causing it is the `search.dispatchEvent` lines, when i comment they the mem does not increase.

I "tried" to solve it adding:

```
search.removeEventListener('focus', focusEvent);
search.removeEventListener('input', inputEvent);
search.removeEventListener('keydown', keyEvent);
```

But it did not change anything in relation to the memory increasing over time, does someone have any idea what else i could try to stop or release the memory growing?